# Difference between "extendable" and "extensible"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can anyone please help me to understand the difference between the 2 words? 
I for one understand that the words have a similar meaning but when is it correct to use them? I use "extendable" for when it's about physical objects such as couch, a spyglass or the pipe that I have at my vacuum cleaner, things like that, that can be folded and unfolded.

What about "extensible" though? I rarely use the latter in conversation and writing and I want to clarify for some friends because to my understanding, does it refer to add parts to an object, in a way, expanding it? Is it a good synonym with expansion?
Thank you and I apologize if this was discussed before but I would like some good examples to know in what cases these words should be used.

Comment: ible, an intrinsic part of; able, that can be extended.

Comment: See also ["Extensible" vs. "extendible"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/90426/7297).

Answer (score 3):

I think of *extensible* as "able to be added to with minimal disruption or reorganization".

You're not the only one who rarely uses the word. I don't think it's very common outside of some technical contexts.

One place I've seen it used is software design. An extensible architecture is one where a program is designed such that new functionality can be added without too much restructuringof the existing code. So someone might say:

> *Using more specialized classes will make this software more extensible*.

(This is discussed further in [the Wikipedia article on Extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility).)

Comment: It can also be used for things that can be "made longer". For example, [Hummingbirds have a long, slender bill with a long extensible tongue adapted for nectar feeding.](http://fishesofgeorgia.uga.edu/gawildlife/index.php?page=speciespages/order_description&class=Aves&order=Apodiformes).

Comment: Isn't similar to my examples? For example, I have a couch and I can "make it longer" and turn it into a bed and I would call this an extendable couch.
If you go to a furniture store for example, what term do you mostly encounter? I am not a native English speaker but I think that "extendable" is more commonly used, even though I only heard it in TV shows/movies and for that reason I am used to using it.

Comment: @Alice I wonder if the difference is that extensible in the sense of "protruding" is biological/medical, and extendable (in tge sense of make longer, not add to) is for objects like those in your examples. I will see if I can verify that guess when I have more time.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you! That would be wonderful! I am trying to explain these differences because I think they are not used properly by my friend and even if she is still against it, which I don't know why even when I am asking from a source where there are also native English speakers around, at least I will know for my knowledge. Because it's one thing when an object has a property to be extended and another when you can expand that object by attaching more additional pieces to it.

Comment: I think there is probably a lot overlap between the two words, so it will be difficult to support a case if you want to say, "These usages are okay, but these are not." One word may sound more normal than another, but correctness is rarely so cut-and-dried in English.

Comment: @Alice I agree with J.R. that there will be many situations where either word would be OK, especially when the words are so similar in meaning and spelling. I think that there are quite a few native speakers who would have to think twice about which word to use if it was a context where they hadn't heard either one used before. I'm not arguing with J.R.'s answer, just pointing out an additional way extensible is used sometimes.

Comment: My sense of it is that "extendable" refers to something that can be expanded in a specific, pre-designed way.  "Extensible" refers to a generic capability of lending itself to be easily expanded in previously undefined ways.

Answer (score 1):

An analogy I use to illustrate the difference is this:

- The collapsible, Slinky-like, pull-to-make-longer hose on your fuel can / jerry can is inherently **extensible**. It can be made longer with no add-on modifications.
- The hose on your Shop-Vac or vacuum cleaner can be made functionally longer by snapping on additional lengths of hose. It is **extendable**.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer in https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90444/422405

> I use extendable in cases where it means the opposite of retractable.
> In other words, a telescoping wand is extendable, the legs of my
> camera tripod are extendable.
>
> I use extensible when I mean that the functionality of something may
> be increased or enhanced by the addition of an extension- an add-on
> module or component. My web browser is extensible because I can add an
> Adobe Flash extension which allows me to view flash content. I think
> it would sound a bit odd to talk about my web-browser being
> extendable.